# c# DateTime, Trim without converting to string

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How can I "trim" a value of a `DateTime` property in c#?

For example, when I get a date it is of the format "10/1/2010 00:00:00".

How can I "trim" 'Time' 00:00:00 without converting this to a String?

Since I use a property of type `DateTime` to manipulate this, I don't need to convert to String.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Your date will always have time regardless although it can be 00:00:00.

Comment: The class name is Date + Time. DateTime. There is no "null time"

Comment: Maybe you are not explaining the issue explicitly enough. As others have said, the DateTime class, by definition, will ALWAYS have the Time portion. If your program depends on there being no time, then maybe something is wrong with the design.. Or, you just aren't making things clear...

Comment: I think you're confusing the structure of the DateTime type with its ToString() representation (which is what the debugger shows). You can't "trim" the "00:00:00" 'cause it doesn't exist until the DateTime is converted into a string. That's why there's multiple ToXXXString() methods.

Answer (score 8):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;    // 10/1/2010 10:44:24 AM
var dateOnly = dt.Date;   // 10/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: And/or dt.ToShortDateString(); when it comes time to display.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Of course the question doesn't have an answer since a DateTime always has a time.

Comment: @Kevin Gale: I disagree. I think it gets to the intent of the OP. Perhaps he will clarify the question or comment on this post.

Comment: @codekaizen: I disagree. He specifically talks about removing the zero time. Of course he is obviously unsure about how a DateTime works so anything is possible.

Comment: @Kevin Gale: Correct, any interpetation may fly, he is obviously new to the `DateTime` type. Therefore I contend my answer is useful. A downvote seems harsh.

Comment: @codekaizen: You're right it was a bit harsh. But neither did you provide any explanation that your response didn't really answer his question because the question doesn't make sense. If you are going to answer the question you think he is asking you should explain that.

Comment: This answered my question, regardless of what the original intention of the poster was.  The word "trim" (which is used in the original question) as it pertains to datetime values, carries a connotation of resetting a part of the datetime to a zero value.  In other languages, including many SQL implementations, this is exactly what a TRIM function does; it does not mean setting the Time portion to null, but means resetting it to 0, or midnight.  Thus, this answer showed me how to "trim" the time from a DATETIME in C#, which is what my google search was.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if the DateTime object can be time-ignorant, the answer is no. You could create a user-defiened class of Date that just returns the Date portion of a DateTime object. If you are just looking to **truncate** the time, see below.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime today = now.Date;
```

or

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime today = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Trim a Date to Hours Minutes, Day ..

```
 DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime t2 = t - new TimeSpan(t.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
```

You can use also TicksPerHour, TicksPerMinute and TicksPerSecond.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just take it from the DateTime object and then .ToString() it?

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
string myTime = current.TimeOfDay.Tostring()
```

You might want to strip the milliseconds from the end...

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. A DateTime always has a time even if the time is 00:00:00

You can only remove that when converting to a string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by some others

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var today = now.Date;
```

is the preffered way. However, since I like the `timtowtdi` philosophi:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var today = now.Add(-now.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: *theoretically* this can get you into trouble because of the time difference between your two statements :)

Comment: thats way I assign the variable first. Since DateTime is a Struct now is a readonly copy of the current date and `now.Add(-now.TimeOfDay)` will always reset the time part to `00:00:00`